# Getting all children from Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll have a script which get all children from HTML subtree which are text type. I wrote sth but it doesn't wokr for any node

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result;
    $.each($("li").contents(), function(i, v){
        if(v.nodeType == 3){
            result = result + " " + v.nodeValue;
        }
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/VgaPC/ . You are getting undefined at first place because you haven't declared the variable result and you adding the result later on to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = "";
    $("li").each(function() {
       result += $(this).text();
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: but why you don't check nodeType == 3?

Comment: you don't have to check if it's a text element, because if there is no text, the value is empty and this doesn't bother you at all. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `result` to empty string:

```
var result = '';
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9372/1/)

If not, `result` is initialized to `undefined`, and

```
undefined + 'someString' === 'undefinedsomeString'
```

Comment: hmmm.... by if i change in script $.each($("div").contents(), function(i, v)... it doesn't write "A B C". Only Foo Bar

Comment: @henio180 And do you want `"Foo A B C Bar"`?

Comment: Yes, i want all subtree (nodes which are text) which are starting with node which i set into script

Comment: @henio Then use `$("div").text()`, or `$("div").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');` to fix whitespaces. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9372/3/)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, I think this more readable:

```
var result = [].slice.call($("li").contents())
    .filter(v => v.nodeType == 3)
    .map(v => v.nodeValue)
    .join(' ');
alert(result);
```

In ES5 it's more verbose:

```
var result = [].slice.call($("li").contents())
    .filter(function(v){ return v.nodeType == 3; })
    .map(function(v){ return v.nodeValue; })
    .join(' ');
alert(result);
```